# Sending bulk emails through SMTP or EWS to avoid being marked as a spam?

Tags: smtp, exchangewebservices, spam

- Does sending emails through SMTP actually helps in avoiding being marked as a spam domain?
- What about EWS (Exchange Web Services)? If I use EWS to send bulk emails, will my chances in being marked as a spam domain increase or decrease or is it irrelevant?

*Back Story:*
I'm trying to figure out the best way to send bulk emails without getting my domain marked as a spam domain.
So far I settled on using EWS, however my colleagues at work informed me that using EWS will be a bad idea as your domain will eventually get marked as a spam domain (by google.com, outlook.com, yahoo.com, etc..) but if SMTP were to be used, then you can avoid this problem.

I searched SO but almost all the questions that have been asked here are in context of technique used to send emails. (check notspam.com or dnsrbl.org to diagnose and check email headers) 
But I couldn't find a question that will answer which method is advantageous in term of avoiding being marked as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Does sending emails through SMTP actually helps in avoiding being marked as a spam domain?

No it make no difference what so ever it's based on the content your sending

> > What about EWS (Exchange Web Services)? If I use EWS to send bulk emails, will my chances in being marked as a spam domain increase or decrease or is it irrelevant?

It will make no difference email your send via EWS will still be sent via SMTP, EWS is the transport your client is using to Send Email to the local Exchange Server of the Mailbox your send from. On the Exchange side at the Hub Server/Edge server the Email you sent will be converted to a MIME message and sent via SMTP to the external recipients. The content that the Antispam services will look at will be identical.

The only advantage I see to using different SMTP server on a complexity different network/IP is that if that SMTP servers IP is blacklisted that won't affect your Exchange infrastructure (Also Exchange will throttle EWS by default so that another issue you would most likely have). As a generally best practice rule sending bulk email from corporate email servers is a bad idea. There are many third party services like https://www.campaignmonitor.com/ or mailchimp etc that will eliminated the potential for you getting blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I will definitely look into third party services as we cannot afford to have our domain blocked by email providers. Might use EWS for small interaction or notifications.